# How to set swipe gesture to the entire activity in Android Studio (Scroll Views issues)

Tags: android, gesture

Here are the relevant pieces of code that I have. Swiping works, but only when swiped on the background of the activity. Most of the space of my activities are taken by the listviews, or textviews and they seem to be "in the way" when swiping. In other words if there was nothing in my activity it would work just fine, but since there are other objects that are "in the way" it doesn't work.

I narrowed it down to the scroll views. All my text views are in scroll views, list views are scroll views by default and this is what causes problem. It simply doesn't allow me to swipe in scroll view.
Any idea how to work around it?

Thank you for your help.

My code:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {...

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myactivity);


gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);

}
```

then the rest of the code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent downEvent, MotionEvent moveEvent, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;

        float diffY = moveEvent.getY() - downEvent.getY();
        float diffX = moveEvent.getX() - downEvent.getX();


            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                //right or left swipe
                  if (Math.abs(diffX) > 100 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 100) {
                      if (diffX >0) {
                          onSwipeRight();
                      } else {
                          onSwipeLeft();
                      }



                  }

            } else {
                //up or down 
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > 100 && Math.abs(velocityY) > 100) {
                    if (diffY >0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
            }
        return result;
    }

    private void onSwipeTop() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe top", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void onSwipeBottom() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe bottom", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    private void onSwipeLeft() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void onSwipeRight() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: implement this in your activity https://github.com/GeeksEmpireNet/FloatIt.Pro/blob/master/FloatItPhone/src/main/java/net/geekstools/floatshort/PRO/Util/UI/SimpleGestureFilterSwitch.java